# Why is Apple Mail showing as 61GB?

Tags: macos, mail.app, storage

Can anyone explain/help with this? (My local Mac techy can't.)

My 2013 Retina MBP (running Mojave) is almost full, but it tells me Mail is somehow using 61GB. It was showing 70GB until I deleted almost all my mails and changed the settings so downloads do not automatically download. What is creating this mysterious 61GB and how to get rid of it (and prevent it from coming back), please?

Comment: Where does it show that? In Mail.app>Account Info? You should check with OmniDiskSweeper (https://www.omnigroup.com/more) or DaisyDisk (https://daisydiskapp.com/) in order to get a better picture where the GB are located

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. It shows when I go to the Apple - About this Mac - Storage. Is there no way to check further without using this external software?.

Comment: Try rebuilding by selecting the target mailbox and going to Mailbox-> Rebuild. Also see if (anyhow) junk or trash is causing it.

Comment: Thanks. But there is no trash or junk to speak of, and there is no 'target mailbox' - just a global figure of 61GB. I think whatever it is lies well below the level of anything I can see or access through the app itself...

Answer (score 1):

Mail is one of the easiest to clean up in most cases.

1. Verify your mail providers have all of your mail stored in the cloud.
2. If you are cloud based, remove each mail account one by one, then repeat the measurement of the databases.

Usually it’s attachments and indexing that take that much space, but when you delete the mail account from settings, that should clean up all the local storage.

If you have local copies of mail, you’ll have to export / back that up to be sure you don’t lose those mails before removing the account.

How much space is used once you delete all accounts or get a good backup and then delete accounts?

If you show a screen shot of how you're measuring, we might have some extra advice, like not using the system information if there are time machine local snapshots (or how to purge them) or if you just need to remove some library files or ask for a database "vacuum" process.

Comment: And if you don’t want local copies of attachments, consider switching from POP to IMAP when you set up the new accounts.

Comment: Oh wow, now you're going a bit out of my depth I'm afraid! I am not sure I can exactly understand all you are asking there, but I can say that I have already gone through all the mailboxes and deleted everything, including the archive and drafts folders. I also found the mail downloads file and purged that. The total of all the mail I deleted, which far outweighs what remains, was 9GB. I don't know how to add a screenshot, but the Apple - About this Mac - Storage is where Mail is still showing 61GB where all my other docs are 125GB, apps are 22GB, system is 20GB. Not sure if this helps you?